# can't upload a file to Amazon S3 using a presigned URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

Posting a file using a presigned url retrieved from lambda got a 403 Forbidden Error

[What I expect is as shown in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb40m.png)

① has an S3 full access policy attached to it

②The lambda is in a VPC private network, code is as follows

```
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'
import { PutObjectCommandInput, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const Bucket = process.env.BUCKET_NAME!

const client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION!,
})

const params: PutObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket,
    Key: `xxxxx/yyyyy`
  }

return await getSignedUrl(client, new PutObjectCommand(params), { expiresIn: 3000 })
```

Returning this URL to the user

Another code I tried

```
import { S3RequestPresigner,  } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'
import { parseUrl } from '@aws-sdk/url-parser'
import { Hash } from '@aws-sdk/hash-node'
import { HttpRequest } from '@aws-sdk/protocol-http'

const Bucket = process.env.BUCKET_NAME

const client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION!,
})

const s3ObjectUrl = parseUrl(`https://${Bucket}.s3.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/yyyyy`)
const presigner = new S3RequestPresigner({
    credentials: { accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY! },
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION!,
    sha256: Hash.bind(null, 'sha256'),
  })
return await presigner.presign(new HttpRequest({ ...s3ObjectUrl, method: 'PUT' }), { expiresIn: 3000 })
```

③S3 Bucket is allowed access from lambdas

④However, if the user uses the URL returned by the lambda in post man, it will result in a 403 Forbidden(SignatureDoesNotMatch) error.

Some of the returned errors

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Something wrong with the code? Or is the permissions of lambda or s3 wrong? Don't know...

Comment: What does the code that uses the presigned URL look like?

Comment: @AnonCoward
sorry
I'm not good at English, so I didn't understand your question.
But as I wrote in the comments, the problem is solved
thank you

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem but answered a related question It was a few hours of making a PUT request instead of a POST I spent a few hours making such a mistake...

Comment: please can you clarify how this is an answer to your question?